# Get AD user by providing fullName and manager full name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

It might look silly but I'm struggling with finding user with Powershell by providing his full name and his manager full name. Purpose of script is to get `SamAccountName` and `Email Address` by using mentioned values which are provided by other team (these are the only unique values I get - getting user by Full Name is not any kind of problem, but it's possible that it'll return multiple results, and that's why Manager Full Name would determine appropriate result).
First I was using simple command

```
Get-ADUser -server $gc -Filter { (CN -eq $uFullName) -and (extensionAttribute4 -eq $mFullName) }
```

It worked great, but unfortunately I noticed that not all accounts use `extensionAttribute4` to hold manager full name. I thought of using Filter on manager property but when I tried to use `(Manager -like "*value*")` it returned that `like` operator isn't supported by this attribute.

I'm still trying to find solution for this but maybe someone will have some solution to this situation.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just pipe your command to `where-object` where you will have access to all of Powershell's comparison operators. A complete use of `-Filter` will likely be faster but since you are already filtering the performance benefits could be minuscule.

Comment: I tried following one `Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object { ($_.Name -eq "value") -and ($_.Manager -like "*value*") }` and it doesn't return anything

Comment: When using `where` your command has to return the properties you filter on. So you must include `-properties Manager` in `Get-AdUser`

Comment: HUGE THANKS!! It worked, didn't have a clue that it needs to be referred as well